# Определение значения VALUE определённого элемента на другой странице через PHP-функцию

Tags: php

Я знаю PHP-функцию `preg_replace(...);`, которая может находить в определённом HTML-файле элемент по ID и изменять его свойства. Существует ли синонимичная функция, которая вместо изменения свойств элемента будет наоборот определять его свойства? То есть например мне нужно узнать значение `value` текстового поля на другой HTML-странице через PHP-функцию. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: сделай  парсер и парси `value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Возвращает все элементы массива,
// содержащие числа с плавающей точкой
$fl_array = preg_grep("/^(\d+)?\.\d+$/", $array);
?> - условия поиска замени и готово.
```